# Миграция начальных данных one to many

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Хочу создать некое кол-во пользователей и привязать к ним биографию (одну и ту же, с полями типа "заполните_меня").
Есть таблица
`user_table`

```
+-------+------+
|user_id|bio_id|
```

и pivvot `user_bio`

классы:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user';

    public function bio()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Bio::class);
    }
}

class Bio extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'bio';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

вношу начальные данные:

```
public function run()
    {
        $user = [...массив на N штук пользователей...];

        $bio = [...массив, по данным которого будет создано N таблиц...];

        foreach ($user as $value) {
            $bio_new = Bio::create($bio);//bio_id на этом этапе === NULL
            $user_new = User::create($value);
            $user_new->bio()->save($bio_new);
        }
    }
```

В результате получаю

```
Unknown column 'user_bio_id' in 'field list' (SQL: update `bio` set `user_bio_id` = 1 where `id` = 1)
```

А такой колонки даже не существует

Comment: Так ее нужно создать. Это стандартный механизм "привязки", который вы описали в моделях. А вы как хотите?

Comment: Но у меня есть pivvot-table `user_bio`